# login authentication using scrapy in python

Tags: python, scrapy

here my write my code to authenticate user but i am not able and also its not giving any error. i am not able to understand where i did wrong.

```
from scrapy.spiders import Spider
from scrapy.http import Request,FormRequest

class LoginSpider(Spider):
    name = 'loginspidername'
    start_urls = ['http://insights.eshopbox.com']
    login_page='http://insights.eshopbox.com/login/'

    def parse(self, response):
        return [FormRequest.from_response(response,method='POST',
                    formdata={'username': 'username', 'password': 'password'},
                    callback=self.after_login)]

    def after_login(self, response):
        # check login succeed before going on
        print 'fdgv'
        if "logout" in response.body:
            print ('logged in')
        else:
            print ('not logged in')
```

any help in this.. thanks in advance..